# Fonts not Displaying in any Browser from Host

Tags: html, css, fonts, localhost

I have spent hours trying to solve this and cannot come up with a solution.

I have fonts in a font folder within the css folder. BebasNeue is the name of the font. It displays fine from my local machine but will not display from my hostgator account. The case is correct and the file names match.

Here is the site: [www.robertpauljensen.com/krjwoodcrafts.com](http://www.robertpauljensen.com/krjwoodcrafts.com/)

Comment: Custom fonts are showing for me- Chrome, Fedora, at least Lato is

Comment: I changed the permissions and now they are displaying. Not sure why hostgator defaulted to the permissions they did, but that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your permission on the font folder, i get 403